# Is there a transition evaluation order in Spring Statemachine?

Tags: spring-statemachine

I'm using Spring Statemachine to model the behaviour of a project. Is there a transition evaluation order, particularly in what concerns internal, local and external transitions? Something like internal transitions are evaluated first/last or something like that.

I've looked at the documentation and also searched Stack Overflow, but I can't find any information regarding that.

Comment: Can you please give a concrete example? SMs should be deterministic. What is the logic behind needing transition evaluation? You are in a current state - a signal comes in - you transition to another state.

Comment: You may want to transition to different states depending on some variable's value, for instance. You can have Guards for that, of course, but imagine I want to have an internal transition each time I receive a given event and increment a counter. When the counter reaches a certain value I want to transition to another state instead. If internal transitions are evaluated first, you need a Guard for the internal transition that returns "false" when the counter reaches that value, but you don't need a Guard for the external transition. Otherwise, you need a Guard for the external transition also.

Comment: according to your example, this is how I will model it - do internal transitions but on each state entry, check the counter - if the counter matches a criteria - send a signal (fire event) that will trigger a transition from the current state to the next one.